# Close button "X" to show default cursor

Tags: magnific-popup

sorry but I can't find the answer.

I want to change the minus magnifying to a normal\default arrow cursor when I'm hovering over the "X" to close the image...this image below doesn't show my cursor but do you know what I'm talking about ? Here is the example ? - codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/vKrqs

[image]

Comment: add `.mfp-close { cursor: pointer!important; }` to your css, is that what you mean? example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdMvgy

Comment: YES! Exactly. Thank you very much. I'm not very good at this stuff (HTML\JAVASCRIPT\CSS)... wanted to learn, came up with a idea and decided to learn as I go.